# NSTableView old selection

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

How do I get the previous selected index of row in `NSTableView`

The methods

```
func tableViewSelectionIsChanging(notification: NSNotification) {
     let index = (notification.object as! NSTableView).selectedRow
     println(index)
}
```

---

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
    let index = (notification.object as! NSTableView).selectedRow
    println(index)
}
```

Both methods print same value. How do I get the index / row which is going to change due to selection ?

---

**Or in simple terms, how do I make a statement like**

```
println("\(Selection changed from \(tableView.oldSelectedIndex) to \(tableView.newSelectionIndex)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before a cell is selected, the function `func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int)` is called on the `delegate`.  Here, you can see both the currently selected row, and the proposed selection.

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {

    // This is the next index
    NSLog("Next index: \(row)")

    // Make sure that a row is currently selected!
    guard self.tableView.selectedRowIndexes.count > 0 else {
        return true
    }

    // Get the currently selected row.
    let index = self.tableView.selectedRow
    NSLog("Previous index: \(index)")

    return true
}
```

NB: This doesn't *exactly* answer your question, because you've asked for the change *after the new selection has occurred*, whereas this gives it just before.  I hope nonetheless that this is sufficient.

Comment: This technique will not work when the user de-selects a row, because `tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int)` is not called.  Instead, use the delegate method `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, selectionIndexesForProposedSelection proposedSelectionIndexes: IndexSet) -> IndexSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by

```
tableView.selectedRow
```

Comment: This answer does not work with multiple selections, and more importantly, this answer returns the selection AFTER the selection has changed, not BFORE. The question specifically asks for the selection BEFORE it was changed.